# iOS: Layer UILabel over TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

We'd like to add a "No Connection" label on top of our Table View such as below when we get network connection errors in our app.

How can you conditionally layer a label on top of the Table View?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add your layer on the keyWindow but make sure to remove after the animation.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(MyUILabel)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom UIView that you will add as a subview to your viewController.view over the table view and animate it's appear and disappear actions.